# How can I style every font in every TextView using 1 line of code?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to style all the hundreds of textviews that I've created over dozens of file using a global style. how can i do this?

Comment: Your question makes no sense - explain more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: watch it, i re edited, please remove your kill

Comment: +1 for caving to downvote pressure and this may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-a-global-style-for-views-in-android

Comment: harper your comment contains the correct answer. submit for points and answer?

Comment: @hunterp: He ( @harper89 ) might not get your message unless you use the `@` symbol in front of his user name.

Comment: @hunterp was in a hurry so just posted real quick. Glad it helped. Upvote to give the link points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here. Maybe even a few additional chunks of info.

[Setting global styles for Views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-a-global-style-for-views-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create separate style resources in /res/values/style.xml

here is a sample style

```
<style name="style_title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dip</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>
```

You can find more info here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html