# Android themes - how to set style for specific view types only

Tags: android, android-styles

Is it possible to create a theme, that will set styles only for specific view types?
For example, if I want the background for the `FrameLayout` objects to be one color, but leave all other views with the default background color of the theme, how would I do that?

The CSS parallel would be `div {background-color:#000000;}`. How can I do that in android?

Edit: I found something for `TextView` only: `android:textViewStyle`, and you can select a style only for `TextView`s. But what about other views? Even Custom views? `FrameLayout` view specifically?

Comment: Hello. Did you find out how to do it?

Comment: Here is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/