# Apply style to every child view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have the following pseudo layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <ACustomView />

    <AnotherCustomView />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have `TextView`s in both of the custom views (inflated from XML). How can i set
style properties (eg. textColor) for every `TextView` in the first custom view? For example i want every `TextView` to be red which are in the first custom view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible.

If you don't want to much typing you can define your own style and add it to each textview or you can create your own textview class where style attributes are set.

For an example use this question/answer:

[Setting global styles for Views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android)

I hope i could help you

Cu
JackZ

Comment: Thanks. Ia made the following solution: the custom view now has xml attributes for settings these styles, and i apply them in the constructor of the view. Its require some coding though. Wish android had css-like selectors. :)