# How to set margin for all TextView using styles.xml

Tags: android, styles, margin

I've read from another post that it's possible to set attributes like color to every TextView in an application: [Setting global styles for Views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android). However, I can't set layout_margin nor layout_height and layout_width attribute using that method to any textView, using "android:textviewStyle". On the other hand, if I use the style attribute and reference it to a style with all the attributes above, it works. Is there a way that you can use global styles and still set margin?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can set padding instead of margin and you will have the same result.