# Android - style.xml takes no effect

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, android-styles

I found topic with instruction - how to set theme for whole application:

[Setting global styles for Views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android)

It does not work for me at all. Here's my code:

style.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--1-->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/TBRadioButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TBRadioButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/state_color_selector</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

state_color_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true">
            <color android:color="#F00" />
        </item>
        <item android:state_checked="false">
            <color android:color="#0F0" />
        </item>
    </selector>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="my.app" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:name=".controller.ApplicationController"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".view.DrawersWidget"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

.java file with RadioButton creation:

```
RadioButton newButton = new RadioButton(ApplicationController.INSTANCE.getApplicationContext());
//...
newButton.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
newButton.setButtonDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(ApplicationController.INSTANCE.getResources(), filteredBitmap));
newButton.setText(someText);
```

Comment: I am not seeing where you apply the style to your button?

Comment: This is theme set for whole application (AppTheme) - isn't it?

Comment: It is but that does not mean it applies the button style to all button in your app, you have to explicity set the button style attribute to the button style you declared.

Comment: Why? Is this really necessary? Why should I pass applicationContext in the constructor then? There's no point in setting global style for application then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the RadioButton, use the Context of the Activity, instead of the ApplicationContext.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.app/my.Activity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File       from drawable resource ID #0x0` occured on line `RadioButton newButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());`

Comment: It seems like there is some error connected with `<selector>` tag, as error disappears as son as I remove it.

Comment: I've never used a color as a drawable `<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="#F00" />`. The #F00 should be replaced with a real drawable? And I've never used a selector inside an item of a theme. Better to add the selector as drawable too?

Comment: The same error after changing `drawable` to `color`. What does it mean to "add the selector as drawable"?

Comment: Inside the res/drawable folder create a my_selector_drawable.xml. Then copy in that file the content of your selector. In your theme reference the drawable as <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_selector_drawable</item>

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question. Your solution works like charm now.