# Parent style for TextView style with AppCompat usage

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-styles

What parent style should I use if I want to set global textViewStyle and maintain backward compatibility with AppCompat? I can't find something like Widget.AppCompat.TextView :

```
<style name="Base_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/GlobalTextViewStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="GlobalTextViewStyle" parent="?????">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium</item>
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android

Comment: Did you tried to don't set a parent? Just this: `<style name="GlobalTextViewStyle">`. Or it's important to set value of `parent` attribute? I'm having the same problem right now, but there are no any competent decision. **I think using `android:...` as parent is bad if you use AppCompat.**

Answer (score 7):

You just need to extend `TextAppearance.AppCompat` style overriding necessary values:

```
<style name="Base_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">?android:textColorHint</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">?android:textColorHighlight</item>
        <item name="android:textColorLink">?android:textColorLink</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_body_1_material</item>
        <item name="textColor">?textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="textColorHighlight">?textColorHighlight</item>
        <item name="textColorHint">?textColorHint</item>
        <item name="textColorLink">?textColorLink</item>
        <item name="textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work. When I use Luiz Fernando Salvaterra solution style is correctly applied to the all textviews.

Comment: @AppiDevo, that means you should upvote and accepts Luiz's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set this style for all your `TextView's` in your app, you can do something like this:

```
<resources>
<style name="YourTheme" parent="android:YourParentThTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/GlobalTextViewStyle </item>
</style>

<style name="GlobalTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="normal_text_white" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/small_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try this as well for `AppCompat` widget.

```xml
<style name="TitleStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
</style>
```