# How to edit text (content) inside an Android View item

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-view, android-styles

I'm trying to style text in`EditText`. I've managed to stytle the `EditText` itself, but not its content. How can I go about changing the font weight, font color, style etc for text held inside the `EditText`?

This is how I style the `EditText` view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="42dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">
    <item android:bottom="3dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_games_black_24dp" />
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#37474f" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then I call it:

```
EditText editText = new EditText( mContext );
editText.setHint(" Find");
editText.setWidth(555);
editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_new_bag_dr);
```

What is the best way to go about it? What options do I have?

**UPDATE**

How can I attach a style defined in an XML to a View?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following:

```
editText.setTextColor("set the color you want");
```

Define your custom style in style.xml and then use

```
editText.setTextAppearance(R.style.yourCustomStyle);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sumit. How can I attach a style defined in an XML to a View?