# How to share properties in an xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a few TextViews in my app and they all have a bunch of styling properties that are all the same. In an effort to keep my code DRY, I'd like to put those properties somewhere shared between all the TextViews. E.g., they all have the same textSize and maxLines. Is it possible for those properties to live somewhere that all the TextBoxes reference?

Comment: Create a custom style and apply to your all textviews.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting global styles for Views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078081/setting-global-styles-for-views-in-android)