# change background of tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i m developing application in which i have to change the background image on different tab..

i m using linear layout to change background for different activity..i m getting output but..my background image is not fill parent ...i want to set background image in whole screen..do u have any idea how can i do that??

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099959/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-an-android-tab-widget or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029074/how-to-change-tab-style-in-android

Comment: Is your issue actually, that the background image is not visible on the tab header portion? The tab-headers are not part of the activity layout you display on the tabs, so you should change your tabhost activity's background on every tab-change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your device screen size and your background image size.

Answer (score 0):

thank you buddy..
i found the answer...i declared Tab host object statically and on click of tab,different activity get called..and i changed the backgrond of tab host by code..and its work...