# Android tab text invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, tabbed-view

I've developed a simple application with TabView. There are two tabs, each tab has a short text and an icon. I've made the icons in the way the tutorials say.
The application looks perfect on the emulator(s), but after loading to the real device (Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 Mini, 2.1update1) there is a problem with displaying active tab. There is an icon barely visible and no text.
Now, I know I can develop custom Tabs, but I'd rather not do that.

What else can I do to make the tab look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a styling issue with the specific android build on your device, try taking a look at this link and play with the styling options.

[How to change tab style in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029074/how-to-change-tab-style-in-android)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I can see there that I can change the tab text color. That seems to be useful, but do you know if I have to do it separately for selected and unselected tab state?

Comment: If you use a drawable.xml file, you can define the states and how they should render.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: It ended up that I needed to rebuild the whole tab styling. Finally I used a views to build my tab content, and this allowed me to use my own tab background color. It's a shame that Android has such cases. Anyway, thanks for your help.