# Android top Tabs doesn't display full name of the tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have developed top tabs(4) in android and set the names of tabs using the set Indicator method of Tab host class.But the complete names of tabs are not adjusted in the tab space.
What should i do to display the whole name of the tabs.I have pasted the image for better understanding.

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know we can't really do anything with TabHost header display. We can't set size of each tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this existing SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3029300/379693

Otherwise define a custom tab:

1. http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136
2. http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/
3. http://android.attemptone.com/layouts/custom-tabs/