# Android. What kind of tabs are these?

Tags: android, android-tabs

I have noticed a few applications recently using a kind of tab effect, but it isn't what I would consider a "normal" tab control.  The "tabs" are not very tall and only 3 show on the screen at a time. Scrolling the screen left or right reveals another tab, whilst one disappears (hard to describe).

I've seen it on the BBC iPlayer Radio app and on TuneIn app.

The following picture shows what I mean on both of those apps ( though not the sliding bit).

http://i42.tinypic.com/28buosy.png

How do they do that?

Comment: not really an expert but i think this whole window is webview..

Comment: maybe one answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029074/how-to-change-tab-style-in-android) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `ViewPagerIndicator`. It is not provided natively, but there is a library: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

They are used along with the `ViewPager`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Thank you.  I'll have a play later today and see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the Pager Sliding TabStrip:

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

There is also a sample app on the play store:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample